# Ajax request from key validation in magento 2

Tags: magento2, form-validation

I need to done an ajax request in **Magento 2**. But for security purpose, I need to check XSS attacks all possible case. In Magento 1 form key validation and in Magento 2 form key validation is quite different.
I need to validate if the form key match or not. One thing is customer may be logged in or logged out. So I can't validate by customer session.

```
var formKey = jQuery("[name='form_key']").val();
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo $baseUrl.'testing/test/index';?>",
    type: "POST",
    data: {form_key:formKey},
    success: function(response){
        try {
        console.log(response);

        }catch(err) {}
    }
});
```

Now from the controller, I need to validate for XSS attack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So Final Code is

Frontend phtml Files: this will load the from key

```
<?php
    //-- form key load
    echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey');
?>
```

**Ajax Request**

```
var formKey = jQuery("[name='form_key']").val();
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo $baseUrl.'testing/test/index';?>",
    type: "POST",
    data: {form_key:formKey},
    success: function(response){
        try {
        console.log(response);

        }catch(err) {}
    }
});
```

**Controller Code**

```
<?php
namespace Equaltrue\Themeoption\Controller\Taxmode;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey\Validator;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

    /**
     * @var Validator
     */
    private $formKeyValidator;

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param Validator $formKeyValidator
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Validator $formKeyValidator = null
    )
    {
        $this->formKeyValidator = $formKeyValidator ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(Validator::class);
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost() && $this->isAjax() && $this->formKeyValidator->validate($this->getRequest())) {
            echo "this post & ajax & valid request.";
        }
    }

    /*
     *  Check Request is Ajax or not
     * @return boolean
     * */
    protected function isAjax() {
        return isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] === 'XMLHttpRequest';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

From the client side, we can get the form key from cookie:

```
$.mage.cookies.get('form_key'); // jQuery.mage.cookies.get('form_key');
```

In your ajax controller, you use `Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey\Validator;` for form key validation.

```
$this->formKeyValidator->validate($this->getRequest())
```

Take a look at `Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\CreatePost` to see more details.

Comment: thanks, bro it's work getting a reference from Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\CreatePost.
but does this lines is Magento 2 code

$.mage.cookies.get('form_key');